# Referencing ranges from Excel call to change formats

Tags: vba, excel, range

I am trying to create a call from a spreadsheet that will change to the format of a cell. When I explicitly enumerate the range (i.e. "C7") my code works. When I make it implicitly within the excel function call, it does not:

If I put =call_color in a cell, "C7" turns green. If I put =Color_Green(C7) in the same cell, it does not work.

```
Sub call_color()
    Dim TestVal As Range
    Set TestVal = Range("C7")
    Call Color_Green(TestVal)
End Sub
Sub Color_Green(ByRef MyRng As Range)
   ' Color Green Macro
    MyRng.Select
    With Selection.Interior
       .Color = RGB(0, 250, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

I would like to be able to make some calculations in vb, and format a cell based on those calculations. How do I pass a range that will allow .interior functions to work?

Comment: You can do this with a sub but you cannot use a UDF called from a worksheet to alter the format of a cell, or the value of any cell but the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use select or selection and provide a parent worksheet reference.

```
Sub call_color()
    Dim TestVal As Range
    Set TestVal = worksheets("sheet1").Range("C7")
    Color_Green TestVal
End Sub

Sub Color_Green(ByRef MyRng As Range)
   ' Color Green Macro
    MyRng.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 250, 0)
End Sub
```